# How to display multiple products under each category in a views grid?

Tags: views, entities

Currently I have a views with grid display that has the fields **Content: Category** and **Content: Title**, and a filter criteria of **Content: type** (is a product). This displays all my ubercart products with their associated category above them. So I have a result like:

- Category 1: product x
- Category 1: product y
- Category 2: product z
- Category 2: product t

What I want is to have each category only appear once with a few products listed below each category. Such as:

- category 1:

  - product x
  - product y
- category 2:

  - product z
  - product t

I tried giving the field **Content: Category** and multiple field setting where all values of the field will be shown in the same row but that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In you view page, click **Settings** under **Format** section next to **Grid** or whatever display type you use.
2. For **Grouping field Nr.1** select **Content: Category**
3. Under **Fields** section, click on the field **Content: Category**
4. Check **Exclude from display**
5. **Save**. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [Views field view](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.